# notification.setLatestEventInfo() error

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

Please can you help me, what should I replace `.setLatestEventInfo` since it gives an error that's can't resolve this method.

This is my code:

```
if (messages.length > -1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"message received",System.currentTimeMillis());
    //PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW), 0);
    PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , defineIntent, 0);

    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, str, "", myIntent);
    notifyDetails.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notifyDetails.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
    Toast.makeText(context, "el rsala " + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
Intent i = new Intent(context, EncryptionActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("Encrypt", str);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Does `Notification` have a method `setLatestEventInfo()` that accepts `(context, str, "", myIntent)`?

Comment: Notification.setLatestEventInfo() has been deprecated for  API Level 23

Comment: in the past I use it and it works correctly but it seems that in the new API they remove this method but I don't know what should I use instead of it

Comment: if you please help me how to use a new method instead of it

Comment: When you use a search engine and search for `notification setLatestEventInfo replacement`, what do you find?

Answer (score 0):

This method is now deprecated-

Use this now-:

```
private NotificationManager mNM;

 mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.app_name);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);


        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_notification, null,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        Intent pedometerIntent = new Intent();
        pedometerIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, Pedometer.class));
        pedometerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                pedometerIntent, 0);

        builder.setContentTitle("Application");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setContentText(text);
       /*notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, text,
                getText(R.string.notification_subtitle), contentIntent);
*/
        mNM.notify(1, builder.build());
```